# New user not saving in mongodb- validation error path is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to create a new user using node passport.js and mongoose but it shows some error like following

```
{ [ValidationError: User validation failed]
message: 'User validation failed',
name: 'ValidationError',
errors:
{ mobile:
  { [ValidatorError: Path `mobile` is required.]
    properties: [Object],
    message: 'Path `mobile` is required.',
    name: 'ValidatorError',
    kind: 'required',
    path: 'mobile',
    value: undefined } } }
```

My model is like below

### user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
  mobile: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
  active:{ type: 'Boolean', default: false},
  generatedOtp:{ type: String},
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date,
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var user = this;

  if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();


bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
    if(err) return next(err);

    user.password = hash;
    next();
});
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password){
  var user = this;
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
}
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

### api.js

```
passport.use('local-signup',new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email', 
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true},
    function(req, username, email, password, mobile, generatedOtp, done) {
        console.log("second");
        User.findOne({ email : email}, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'That email is already taken.'});
            } else {
                var secret = "mysecretkey";
                var code = otp.generate(secret);
                console.log(code);
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.name    = username;
                newUser.email    = email;
                newUser.password = password;
                newUser.mobile = mobile;
                generatedOtp: code;


                newUser.save(function(err, res) {
                    if(err) {
                            console.log(err);

                    } else {
                        console.log("right");
                    }        
                });
            }           
        });       
    }
));



router.post('/pages/auth/register', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/pages/auth/login', 
    failureRedirect : '/pages/auth/register', 
    failureFlash : true 
}));
```

Using this I can't create a new user. please suggest how to solve this.

Comment: Error says you what is a problem, in your user model mobile field is required, `newUser.mobile = mobile;` seems mobile is not defined

Comment: I am sending the mobile number but it shows undefined

Comment: console.log all the fields you receive in the function see if you are actually getting them or is there a bug.